# How to trigger multiple container dynamically in AWS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

**Requirement:** We have n no.of client(region specific), we need to do some calculations daily on client data and we need to store the data in DynamoDB and this process should be dynamic.

**Problem:** We couldn't find any details on how we can trigger the multiple container dynamically using AWS Fargate which should take some input such as client ids.

We planned to use AWS Lambda + Fargate as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start containers for a task definition using AWS ECS [run-task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html) api

- Define a task definition with container and default environment variables.
- ECS Run Task with launchType Fargate(requires no management of EC2), can be triggered either from Lambda or from cloud watch event rule.
- Pass in `ContainerOverrides` with additional attributes and environment variables when running the task with additional information for that particular run.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Using these steps can we trigger the container per client account ?

Comment: Per client account, meaning running multiple containers with different environment variables related to multiple clients or running containers in multiple AWS accounts? Either one can be done with same approach.

Comment: Like if we have 10 clients, we want to trigger 1 container per clients. so we want to trigger 10 containers with 10 client ids. We will be using only 1 AWS account. is this use case achievable using the above steps ?

Comment: let's say we have an environment variable called CLIENT_ID , when we run-task we can pass in the clientId for which we want to run the task in ContainerOverrides

Comment: so as per my understanding, we need to get the client information from Lambda and we need to pass the CLIENT_ID to ContainerOverrides correct ?

Comment: Exactly. That would be best. Otherwise, we will need multiple task definitions, which is not ideal.